# How to make ID "Primary Key" Field set number based on Rows rather than AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, unique, auto-increment

Right now I have my ID field as the primary key in MySQL and have AUTO_INCREMENT on. What I want to know is how to make the ID represent the number of that row in the table rather than giving it a number when it's inserted, then sticking with that number? Because when I delete something, then that number isn't used. I want them all to be unique based on row count.

Comment: Do You mean that You would like to reuse deleted ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always have a primary key. Either a basic auto increment int or a composite key of multiple fields. It helps your DB do it's job and comes in handy when you want to have relationships. Add a field called `RowIndex` and renumber it when you delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table don't add the AUTO_INCREMENT key word

For existing table, use

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name> MODIFY COLUMN <Column_Name> INTEGER;
```

to remove the AUTO_INCREMENT and the Primary key will be kept.